# how to access javascript custom global variable in another function

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I have developing phonegap android application. I'm trying to establish the communication between  javascript and android java classes.

For Communication i have used addJavaScriptInterfaceMethod in android main activity.So that i can use java object and method in javascript.

following is the Java Code :

```
 public class Activity extends DroidGap
  {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/jq3.html");
            MapTablesWrapper table = new MapTablesWrapper();
            super.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new MapTablesWrapper(), "tables");

           }
     }
```

And in javascript :the following code does not printing the table value.It's alerting undefined

```
var tableName = tables.getTableName();
function(){
       alert(tableName);

 }
```

And if i declare var table inside the function.Its printing the tableName and following code is

```
 function(){
       var table = tables.getTableName();
       alert(tableName);
 }
```

But i would like to  declare variable outside of the function and want to use that varaible in inside the function.

Comment: Try `var global = {table  : tables.getTableName};

function(){
       alert(global.table);
 }` you can rename `global` as your JS file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
var global = {
    table : null
};

function()
{
   global.table = tables.getTableName();
   alert(global.table);
}
```

you can rename global as your JS file name, so that this variable can be accessed all the functions in the current file and also in any other JS File by using your `fileName.table` here it is `global.table`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I used the same code in my app.and Its not recognizing the table variable. I'm getting error stating that RefferenceError : table is not defined